# NSPredicate filter based on one to many values

Tags: ios, core-data, filtering, nspredicate

I have 2 entities with a one to many relationship. `Category` represents my section headers and `SubSubCategory` represents my rows.

```
Category
{
    name:string
    subs<-->>SubCategory
}

SubCategory
{
    name:string
    numbervalue:NSNumber
}
```

Currently I can use `NSPredicate` to filter my sections based on name.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name==%@",@"anamevalue"];
```

Now I want to further filter this predicate to only return categories that have a `Subcategory` with a `subvalue == 1`.

How can I filter the `Category` entity based on the values in its one to many children?

I tried something like this but its no good.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name==%@ AND subs.numbervalue==%@",@"anamevalue",1];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll do a predicate like the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@ AND ANY subs.numbervalue == %@)", @"anamevalue", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

The `ANY` is a predicate modifier that returns true only if there is at least one object in subs collection for which the comparison returns true.

The same result could be done by means of `SUBQUERY`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thats brilliant thanks. Could you share a link to list of Predicate modifiers? I never came across that in the nspredicate programming guide

Comment: Looks for **Predicate Programming Guide**. Here the [Aggregate Operations section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891) where you can find some useful info. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in your predicate is wrong. You are passing an integer value as a string.

Your predicate should be

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name==%@ AND subs.numbervalue==%i",@"anamevalue",1]
```

Other than that it looks correct.